# How would one send a String from C to Ruby on Rails app over a network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, networking, oauth-2.0

I have a String generated in C indicating low level platform details of the client, and I need to send this String to a server which will be receiving it through a Rails app.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add more details about your environment and how the rails app is structured

Comment: The C script fetches the client system information and sends it over to the app. The C script is run by the client with sudo privileges. As per the Rails app, it is hosted on a test dev server on heroku and accepts all incoming connections from a whitelisted ip (manually stored). This works on using a local Rails app to send the information but the objective is to use a purely C solution which will be convenient for the client.

Comment: @MiaSantara Do not ask for upvotes, please; that isn't how things are done here.

Answer (score -1):

You can either create a `TCP Client` or `HTTP Client` in your C program - a listener on Rails app will pick it up. I would recommend `HTTP Client` use `libcurl` (if it is Windows platform - it has `WinHTTP`).

Here is using LibCurl to do a post with the string
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html

If you decide `TCP Client`, support is available using Sockets interface

For TCP Client look for Client Code
http://www.programminglogic.com/example-of-client-server-program-in-c-using-sockets-and-tcp/

Comment: The listener in the Rails app seems not to work when using a C code while it works in case of a local Rails app. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I recommend running the network analyzer and then please post your observations.

Comment: Also try this - To listen on all addresses, which will allow you to connect from other machines on the local network, you must explicitly bind to a more permissive address. Try this:

rails server --binding=0.0.0.0